# setup cordova inappbrowser in android studio

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, inappbrowser

I have just start rewriting my android app that I build it with cordova .This time with android studio.
I wanted to build something like [inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md) that we had in cordova this time in android studio that we can hide it show it add script to it and ... .
At least show a web page independently .
I want to know how can I do that in androd studio ? 
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out good information here : 

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html
And also you can read more here : 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html